# angular2 router become undefined in subscribe method

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-observables

As the title explains it, the `router` object become undefined when it's called inside a `subscribe` member.

Let me show you some code:

```
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
   password = '';
   email = ''; 

  constructor(
      private _router: Router,
      private authService: AuthService
  ) { }


  sendLogin(): void {
       this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
                   .subscribe(function(token){
                     console.log("Success Response" + token)
                     this.token = token
                     // TOKEN Here is good
                     // now I want to change my page, but
                     // _router -> undefined
                     this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

                   },
                     error =>  console.log(error));
     }
```

the method `sendLogin()`is called when submitting a form.
every varibales from the form are good.

The process reach the `subscribe` perfectly, but then 
`this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);`
 gives me :

> EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use an arrow function to preserve the `this` context.

```
sendLogin(): void {
       this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
                   .subscribe( token => {
                     console.log("Success Response" + token)
                     this.token = token
                     // TOKEN Here is good
                     // now I want to change my page, but
                     // _router -> undefined
                     this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

                   },
                     error =>  console.log(error));
     }
```

Comment: Oh, simple ! 
Thanks !

Comment: of course, I just have to wait a couple of minutes before validation

Answer (score 0):

To avoid arrow function, you can use `bind` to bound the `this` context.

```
// ...
this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
  .subscribe(function(token){ //.. your code }.bind(this),
    error => console.log(error));
} // ...
```